# SQL Script to define a table schema using values from another existing table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I have a table in MySQL which is of the following form

```
ID   Team   Task
-----------------
1       Team01       Task_01
2       Team02       Task_02
3       Team02       Task_01
```

The values in the Team and Task column are repetitive.

I need to collect the distinct tasks from the table and use it to create a new table whose schema would be of the form **<strike>Table (Task_01 varchar(20),Task_02 varchar(20));</strike>** 
***Table (Team varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY, Task_01 int, Task_02 int)***

Upon creation , I need to populate this new table with frequency of the tasks performed by respective teams.

Need some directions to proceed ahead. Thanks.

**[EDIT]**

The expected output is another table as shown below

```
Team   | Task_01 | Task_02

Team01 |    1    |   0
Team02 |    1    |   1
```

Just need help/ideas on how to create the schema(via **SQL Scripts** only) once all distinct tasks are obtained from the given table.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in MySQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thank you for pointing out the difference. I was unaware of it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GvanJoic Your current schema seems better to me than the one you want to create. Repetitions aren't necessarily bad. Read some more about [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Yes, actually I think your schema is fine as it is.

Comment: @fancyPants: If the table is left as it is, then how shall the Frequency(Team,Task) be obtained?

Comment: What do you mean with "frequency"? What's the desired result?

Comment: @fancyPants: Expected Output added. Unique values of the Task column of original table are new variables/identifiers in the schema for second table. So frequency would mean "how many times TeamXX has performed Task_YY". Since in the original table, multiple such values are possible, I just wanted to sum it up and place them in the second table. Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`ID` int, `Team` varchar(6), `Task` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`ID`, `Team`, `Task`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Team01', 'Task_01'),
    (2, 'Team02', 'Task_02'),
    (3, 'Team02', 'Task_01')
;
```

You would usually just do this

```
SELECT
Team, Task, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Team, Task;
```

to get this result

```
|   TEAM |    TASK | COUNT(*) |
|--------|---------|----------|
| Team01 | Task_01 |        1 |
| Team02 | Task_01 |        1 |
| Team02 | Task_02 |        1 |
```

which is not in the desired format, but usually formatting is done in application layer. So this is what I recommend. It's easy and performant and has no drawbacks like what do you do when you want to add another task? You would add another column. When a team has nothing to do with this task, it has NULL values in this column. This is bad. Anyway...if you absolutely want to have your output like in the question and not do it on application level, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
Team, 
COUNT(IF(Task = 'Task_01', 1, NULL)) AS Task_01,
COUNT(IF(Task = 'Task_02', 1, NULL)) AS Task_02
FROM Table1 t
GROUP BY Team
```

Result:

```
|   TEAM | TASK_01 | TASK_02 |
|--------|---------|---------|
| Team01 |       1 |       0 |
| Team02 |       1 |       1 |
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing. I'll have to admit,it took some time to really grasp your answer, but in the end it was great. Thanks.